# Need to adapt MFC, c++ native application to OS Font Scaling,

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc, highdpi

We need to adapt an existing MFC, C++ native application (GUI) so the text will enlarge with user preference in system preference:
Windows Settings|Ease of Access|Display|Make text bigger.

Nowadays application will scale their text depending on this user preference.  I have found links explaining how to do this using C# or C++/WinRT:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.textscalefactor

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/text-scaling

We would like to use a native C++ API in order to ease the development effort.  Building bridges to C# or c++/WinRT would also complexify our solution.

We have already adapted our application to DPI scaling.

Thanks for your help